# At which point changing a file changes the execution's outcome?

Tags: python

Say I have a module `foo.py`, with some code, and a script `main.py` that includes `foo` and is executed with `python -m main`.

At which point changing the code of `foo` affects the outcome of `python -m main`?

Specifically, does calling `import` "freeze" the file in the sense that future execution is not affected by changing it?

Example of `main.py`:

```
input()
import foo
input()
import foo
print(foo.f())
```

On which circumstances the modification of a module file can affect the outcome of the execution?

My question is related with the following:

If I have a code under version control and run it, and checkout a different branch, the code from the different branch will be run if some `import` is called lazily (e.g. on a function to avoid circular depedencies). Is this true?

Comment: when you call import the module is taken, even if you call import again python would know that is already in the "session" and will not bring it again. that is why there is a `reload` function

Comment: So, in principle, modules imported the first time within a function can be changed during execution, and the changes will be taken into account only when that function is called.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules):

> A module can contain executable statements as well as function definitions. These statements are intended to initialize the module. They are executed only the *first* time the module name is encountered in an import statement.

So changing the module on disk will not have any effect once the module has been `import`ed once. You can see this yourself: have a file `foo.py` that prints "foo" when imported:

```
print("foo")
```

and a file `main.py` that imports `foo` multiple times:

```
import foo
import foo
import foo
```

and you can see that when you run `main.py`, the output is only one `foo`, so `foo.py` only runs once.

(Note that there is a function [`importlib.reload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload) that attempts to reload the module, but it is not guaranteed to replace all references to the old module.)

With regard to your edit, yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

In [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-import-system)

> When a module is first imported, Python searches for the module and if
>   found, it creates a module object [1](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-import-system), initializing it.

Once this object is created it will be used even if in another module is reimporting it, python keeps track of already imported modules.
If you want to reload them you have to do it manually, check the built-in [`reload`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#reload) for python2 or [`imp.reload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html#imp.reload) for python3

Comment: Thanks. I had read the documentation. I expanded the question to clarify what I meant in terms of version control.